# Certbot (и не только) не видит открытый порт 80

Tags: nginx, сервер

Работаю с серверами последнюю неделю. Не мой профиль, но шаг за шагом не торопясь картинка вырисовывается и иногда возникают вопросы, на которые не могу найти ответ.

**Вводные**

1. У меня есть root-доступ к серверу(ubuntu 20.04)
2. У меня есть hostname, пусть будет host1 (на внешний ip, обычный хост, ipv4)
3. И набор ПО и утилит, которыми я так или иначе пользуюсь (nginx, certbot, python3, gunicron и т.д.)
4. Есть маршрутизатор, к которму у меня доступа нет, но могу сделать заявку на изменения, которые могут мне потребоваться, если это не нарушает меры безопасности и здравый смысл
5. Маршутизатор пробрасывает порты 80 и 443 до моего сервера.
6. На сервере поднят nginx, который слушает 80 порт и пробрасывает запросы на тестовую страничку (максимально просто, чтобы исключить ошибки здесь)
7. через `ufw` на сервере открыты порты 80 и 443

**Что происходит**

Если я перехожу по адресу `http://host1/test_page` я попадаю на мою тестовую страничку. Запросы посылались из других сетей, подсетей и с мобильных телефона мобильной сети.

Если я перехожу по адресу `http://my_ip` (my_ip = ip адресу) я попадаю на стартовую страницу nginx'a (или `default_server` в терминах конфига по умолчанию).

То есть, все выглядит вполне себе верно и работает корректно на данном этапе. Можно сделать вывод, что порт 80 открыт и доступен для запросов. Но самое интересное происходит, если я пойду на какой нибудь сервис по проверке открытых портов (не реклама, но например [этот](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/)). Данный сервис показывает, что порт номер 80 - закрыт. Ок. Но запросы, же, проходят по host и по ip.

Попробуем запросить ssl сертификат для хоста при помощи certbot. Ответ выглядит примерно вот так:

```py
Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: nginx). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
  Domain: host1
  Type:   connection
  Detail: Fetching http://host1/.well-known/acme-challenge/GVwYM0d6yWlHZHbDeAhdHGDd_BMc61S7kQjFRr: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
```

И если пробежаться по логам, то там только несколько попыток и фиаско как результат.

Есть у кого мысли как все это поправить? Основная цель для меня сейчас это получить ssl сертификаты.

Comment: 0) Убедиться, что вы по HTTP попадаете в тот самый nginx, который в надо попасть.

Comment: @gbg 100% попадание туда куда надо. Смотрю по `access.log` nginx'a

Comment: Нет ни скрипта запуска certbot, ни логов ошибок из error.log. Возможно причина в том, что certbot создает файлы в одном месте, а nginx пытается отобразить из другой директории...

Comment: @AndreyMihalev не понял про скрипт запуска certbot. `sudo certbot certonly --nginx` - я вот это использую. В error логах nginx'a только два `[alert] open socket #5 left in connection 4` и  `[notice] signal process started`

Comment: Делайте трассировку до своего IP. Проверяйте работу сайта через vpn из другого региона например. Интернет на физ.лицо?

Comment: @AndreyMihalev другая страна. У фирмы свой дата-центр.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос решен.

Ошибок в конфигурациях с моей стороны не оказалось.

Помог комментарий от @AndreyMihalev. Была запущена трасировка до IP из внешней сети, которая не относится к нашим локальным, рабочим и административным. Увидел где затыкается запрос (оказалось в ip адресах внешнего хостинга). Создал им `issue`. Они что то подшаманили и закрыли мой запрос с результатом `решено`. Что было не могу сказать теперь и отчет они пришлют только по запросу не известно когда.